# Configuring Apache htaccess for Symfony 2 in Subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have Symfony 2 app outside webroot and I created a symlink from `var/www/blog` to `/.../Symfony/web`

It appears like htaccess or something is not working as my css are not rendering (on 1 site), I have 2 similar apps and 1 works, 1 doesn't

```
<Directory /labs/Projects/SimpleSymfonyBlogWork/Symfony/web>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /SimpleSymfonyBlogWork/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

`htaccess` experts could you point out my mistake? Or do you need more info?

Symfony users: in Zend Framework theres a `baseUrl('css/styles.css')` view helper that will output something like `http://site.com/folder/css/styles`. Is there something like that in Symfony 2?

**UPDATE**

I looked online and tried using Aliases instead

```
Alias /SimpleSymfonyBlogWork/ /labs/Projects/SimpleSymfonyBlogWork/Symfony/web
<Directory /labs/Projects/SimpleSymfonyBlogWork/Symfony/web>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Still same problem ...

Comment: you only have the problem for the assets?

Comment: Ya, for now. Since they are the only things I need to link manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute assets path, you can try the `asset` function in your twig template:

```
{# in some twig template #}

<link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

Comment: Is there a PHP alternative for this?

Comment: Yes `echo $view['assets']->getUrl('css/style.css');`